# I want to show EditText record of first Custom ListView to second Custom ListView EditText

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have created two Custom `ListViews`. Both have two `TextViews` and one `EditText`. I want to show the `EditText` record of first `ListView` within the second `ListViews` `EditText`. In my code it only shows the two `TextView` records, but not the `EditText` record

```
   public class Mmnue extends Activity 
   {

   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menuitem);


    final ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final ListView lisView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);


    MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> map;

    /*** Rows 1 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Butterscotch");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 10");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 2 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Birthday Cake");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 100");

    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 3 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Black  Crunch");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 102");

    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 4 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Industrial Chocolate");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 200");

    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 5 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Coffee Molasses Chip");
    map.put("Code", " Rs 500");

    MyArrList.add(map);    
    lisView1.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter(this));
    Button btnGetItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetItem);
    btnGetItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {                

    lisView2.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter2(getApplicationContext()));
            }
            });}


    public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context context;

    public CountryAdapter(Context c)
    {
    //super( c, R.layout.activity_column, R.id.rowTextView, );
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return MyArrList.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mmnue, null);
     }
        // ColID
    TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
    txtID.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("ID") +".");
        // ColCode
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
    txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));

    /*EditText quan = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    quan.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("edt"));
    */

    return convertView;

    }

   }


public class CountryAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context context;


    public CountryAdapter2(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MyArrList.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
     public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null)
    {convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mmnue, null);
    }

    // ColID
    TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
    txtID.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("ID") +".");
    //txtID.setText(name);
    // ColCode
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
    txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));
    //txtCode.setText(rate);

    EditText quan = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    String  quant = quan.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(Mmnue.this,""+quant ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    return convertView;
     }
     }
```

Comment: You want the string in the 1st edit text(of 1st list view) to populate the edit text in the 2nd edit text view(of 2st list view), automatically?

Comment: not automatically on Button Click Event

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show selected record of Custom list view on Toast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738872/how-to-show-selected-record-of-custom-list-view-on-toast)

Answer (score 0):

Because within your `Button - onClick` you define:

```
lisView2.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter2(getApplicationContext()));
```

which simply creates a new `Adapter`without the information from your `EditText` values of ListView1. You should set the Adapter like

```
lisView2.setAdapter((CountryAdapter) lisView1.getAdapter()));
```

This won't have any effect yet, because you are not storing the `EditText` values. You need a **DataObject** within your `Adapter` which saves the `EditText` values. This tutorial might help: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html